# Search address in current city

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Im using Google Maps in my website and when I use the search box, the suggestions of city for the typed address are not related to the current location or the center position of the map. I
I get current latitude and longitude using

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initialize);
```

and configure the map by doing:

```
function initialize(position) {
   var thePoint = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
   var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 14,
      center: thePoint
   };
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
   circle = new google.maps.Circle({radius: 25, center: thePoint});
}
```

What I need to do to get the first option of the search box to show my current city?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SearchBox` only has one option you can control, its `bounds`

> **bounds** Type:  LatLngBounds|LatLngBoundsLiteral
>   The area towards which to bias query predictions. Predictions are biased towards, but not restricted to, queries targeting these bounds.

Your only option is to set that to some function of your center (the resulting map bounds is probably most reasonable).  That only "biases" the results.

Doesn't guarantee anything about the first option of the search box.

Comment: Tried that, and as you said I don't get the result I need. I get the exactly same set of results in the same order.

Comment: When I use this searchbox from android, I get the first option the current city Im right now. That doesn't happen in browser (yes, I have the location enabled and allowed for that website and gets the coordinates)

Comment: What is "the result I need"? Any example of what you expect and what you get?

Comment: @MrUpsidown As I said, I need the first returned result is in my current city. Example: Im in L.A. and I search Hollywood Blvd 123, I need to get "Hollywood Blvd 123, Los Angeles, California" as first result and not "Hollywood Blvd 123, Miami, Florida" as first result. Because is less relevant.

Comment: If I am setting the `bounds` property as explained above, around the city of LA, and I enter "Hollywood Blvd 123" then the first result I get is *123 Hollywood Blvd, Los Angeles, California, USA*. What about you update your question with your code, a search example and the results you get? You must be doing something wrong. Either your bounds object is incorrect, or something else is going on, but without seeing your code, we can't tell you what it is!